# Updates to the site

Tags: discussion, design

My name is Stéphane and I'm the designer at Stack Exchange who made the design of this site. You may have noticed some updates to the design lately.

The updates are part of a SE network-wide update to a new base css framework (the code which display the design).

The updates allow us to:

- Have sharper / more beautiful design on retina displays
- Fix layout bugs
- More easily add new features to all of our sites in the future

If you see any bugs please let us know.

Thanks!

Comment: Y U TURN OF SUBPIXEL ANTIALIAS?! Also, body font looks weird, georgia looks better to me for this site.

Comment: Hi. May I ask you to take a look at this chat room message? It is a request about designing an advertisement image for community promotions ads of TeX.SX. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21041063#21041063

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

There is no longer a downvoted-answer class, and downvoted answers are no longer greyed out. (As mentioned [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20218342#20218342)).

Is this intentional?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the updates!

I have a singular concern.

I don't know if it's just me, but it appears that question titles now have serif font that is somewhat harder to read, because the characters seem to be wider than those of other StackExchange sites. It's also slightly disorienting as the rest of the page is in a sans serif font.

Probably need other people's opinions on this to verify.

Here's a site that hasn't got its changes yet from what I can tell, for comparison:

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Academia originally had a specific font for the question titles, nothing changed here. Unless you were not able to view them and now you're able to. Could you tell me your browser/os version ?

Comment: FireFox 35, Windows 7 Latest Update. I can just swap my font out for Arial if that's the case. Something feels different about it, though. I remember looking at Academia last night and then today the changes are a bit weird for me.

Comment: The question titles color changed, it was a dark grey and it's now blue. That's the main difference.

Comment: You're right! I'm just crazy then @_@

Comment: I also have the feeling that the font of the site is changed...

Comment: Same opinion - the fonts for front page question titles and votes/answers/views look a bit weird, and a tad too small for my taste. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/4MwU3sh.png. Latest Ubuntu, Firefox 35.0.1. Could just be habit, though.

Comment: Like they're wider, right? I feel like they're wider. @FedericoPoloni The font itself just feels like the Os are super-round compared to Arial.

Comment: I feel that the font is smaller and the background is whiter. I hope this is a good switching, cause I feel unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a bug so much as an inconsistency. The answer windows use a fixed-width font, but the box to enter comments uses a proportional font. This is jarring to the user.